# extract date from string that contains time as well in C#

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I get an string from one of DTO i.e. "2020-05-17T00:00:00"  and this is automapped to one of view model. Actually i only need date part i.e. 2020-05-17 and not time part from it.

Within automapper i tried directly formatting string in following way.

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",)
```

but automapper says that this can only be done within a type and not during mapping.

Also tried below way but still failed to format string.

```
   .ForMember(src => src.FromDate, act => act.MapFrom(dest => DateTime.ParseExact(dest.FromDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
```

Not able to track where the issue is.

Any pointers or help is welcomed.

Comment: Why are you using strings at all? Why do either DTO have a string property instead of a date type? This is formatting, not mapping. That's a serious bug. Use the correct types, (DateTime, DateOnly in .NET6) and let the UI format the types to strings

Comment: If one type had a DateTime or DateTimeOffset and the other a DateOnly it would make sense to add a custom map, assuming AutoMapper doesn't already map between the date types. `DateTime.ParseExact(dest.FromDate, "yyyy-MM-dd",` doesn't do what you asked at all. It *parses* a string of the form `yyyy-MM-dd` into a `DateTime`. It doesn't manipulate strings or formate a DateTime into a String. If you're absolutely certain the strings are valid, you could use `fromString.Left(10)` to get the date part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get a DateTime instead of string then use the method

```cs
.ToShortDateString()
```

If you can't get a DateTime, convert the string to DateTime with

```cs
DateTime oDate = DateTime.Parse(iDate);
```

Then use the toshortdatestring

Comment: thanks man. Appreciate your time for suggesting this. Was worth for me.